# Is still true that every nonzero Prime Ideal is Maximal in a noncommutative PID?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Basically what I said in the title: I can't find a proof that doesn't make use of commutativity. I know that Commutativity is generally taken for granted in a domain, but I wanted to know in general, since this not being true would break "PID implies Dedekind" in a noncommutative setting.

Comment: PID usually carries into its definition that of a *commutative ring* ...

Comment: I know. Usually. Here there is an exemple of noncommutative PID: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724289/an-example-of-a-noncommutative-pid

Comment: You also have to clarify what you want to mean by *prime*. Do you mean you want the general definition of prime, or the commutative definition applied to noncommutative rings?

Comment: Someone can correct me or help me out on this one, but if $(3)$ is a maximal ideal of the Hurwitz quaternions, it would be a counterexample. The Hurwitz quaternions are a right and left PID that isn't commutative.

Comment: The prime ideal definition that I always used is that there aren't two elements outside the ideal which product belongs to the Ideal, but I can see how this is influenced by commutativity. 
As for the second comment I genuinely don't understand what you are stating and what you are asking. Also to have a counterexemple we should find an Ideal which is at least NOT maximal, and then also prime. But maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: I think you have to clarify what you mean by prime, but also by PID (are we talking about left ideals, right ideals, bilateral ideals, all of them ? what would you mean by principal bilateral ideal : that any ideal is generated by one element, or that it's of the form $aR, Ra$, or $RaR$ ?)

Comment: Since I don't have a clear setting defined (I'm trying to understand what results are dependant on which properties in a commutative setting) I'd go with only right principal ideals (since the commutative proof would still work with bilateral ideals) and right ideals in general.
By prime ideal I already said that I mean an ideal which is not the whole ring and there aren't two elements outside the ideal which product is an element of the ideal. This definition is not influenced by noncommutativity. 
Then a right principal ideal would be in the form ***aR***.